# Configuring QT for android development

Tags: android, qt, qt-necessitas

I've been trying for months to configure Qt for android app development. Following the instructions, I found somewhere on the internet, I downloaded ' qt-opensource-windows-x86-android-5.6.1-1.exe' from Qt archive, 'java jdk 1.8' 'Apache-Ant 1.9'and 'Android NDK'. For Android SDK, however, I'm using SDK I downloaded for Android Studios (Android studios works absolutely fine on my PC). I added all these to QT configuration but it shows some [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xUPb.png) . There is no android compiler shown in the list of available compilers. For this reason I cannot make a proper kit for android.

How can I add an android compiler? I have [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmFY7.png) in my QT folder. How can I add usable kits?
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I think if the error you mentioned was about `"Qt versions for 3 architectures are missing"`, then you no need worry, you can discard that. Coming to the compiler have you seen any auto-detected kits say like this `"Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.6.0)"` in your Build & Run settings.

Comment: Have you tried to add kits manually ?. If not, check this [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html)

Comment: No, I can't see an auto-detected kit. However, 2 Qt versions are available named "QT 5.6.1 Android armv7" and "QT 5.6.1 Android x86" but it also shows a red dot beside the name saying "No compiler can produce code for this Qt version. Please define one or more compilers"

Comment: Okay got it, what do you see under Compiler options

Comment: I see [this](https://s31.postimg.org/v4bjqda6z/Capture.png)  under compiler options..

Comment: From the picture it is evident that you don't have any Android GCC compilers available. I will suggest you to update your Android NDK may be download fresh from the [site](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html) and update your NDK. Usually you can find the list of compilers supported in the toolchains folder of your NDK directory.

Comment: After downloading android NDK from the official site, it works finally. Thanks very much.